# Not linking to the correct id

Tags: php, laravel

i am new to code and wondering why my comment id is not linking to the correct post id.

This is my comment controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Tweet;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Comment;



class CommentController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
      return view('comments',[

      'tweets' => Tweet::all()
    ]);
    }
    public function store(Tweet $tweet)
    {


      $attributes = request()->validate(['comment_body' => 'required|max:255']);


          Comment::create([

        'user_id' => auth()->id(),
        'tweet_id' => $tweet->id,
        'comment_body' => $attributes['comment_body']
      ]);


      return redirect('/comments/{$tweet->id}');
    }
}
```

This is my comment.blade.php file

```
    x-app>
  <div class="border border-blue-400 rounded-lg px-8 py-6 mb-8">
{{dd($tweets)}}
 @foreach ($tweets as $tweet)
    <form method="POST" action="/comments/{{$tweet->id}}">
    @csrf
    @endforeach



    <textarea
      name="comment_body"
          class="w-full"
          placeholder="Reply to this tweet"
          required
          autofocus
           >
         </textarea>

           <hr class="my-4">

           <footer class="flex justify-between items-center">
             <img
             src="/images/twitter.jpg"
             alt=""
             class="mr-2 rounded-full"
             width="50"
             >


           <button type="submit" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 rounded-lg shadow px-10 text-white h-10">Comment</button>
     </footer>
  </form>
  @error('body')
    <p class="text-red-500 text-sm mt-2">{{ $message }} </p>
  @enderror
  </div>
    <div class="border border-gray-300 rounded-lg">

  <p class="p-4">No comments</p>






  </div>


</x-app>
```

The main problem is I hit comment and instead of it entering the database as it should e.g I comment on a tweet with an id of 2 in the database and the comment will have a tweet id of 1 which is what is meant to link them but instead, all the comments are going to the tweet id 1.

Comment: your `@endforeach` should be before `</form>` closing tag otherwise it will create so many `<form>` tag without any closing

Answer (score 1):

Your controller method is expecting a 'Tweet' Model, not `$tweet->id`, which you are posting.

You can confirm this by doing a print_r on `$tweet` in the store method of your controller.

```
print_r($tweet);
```

Change your form action to be

```
<form method="POST" action="/comments/{{$tweet}}">
```

**IF YOU ARE NOT USING A RESOURCE ROUTE**

Your POST route for this action must be setup like this:

```
Route::post('/comments/{tweet}, 'CommentController@store');
```

As per JoshBonnick's comment, the form opening tag is within your `@foreach` loop in the blade example you gave, but the closing is not, you probably want to move your `@endforeach` below your closing `</form>` tag

You also have an error in your redirect in the controller, you do not need the braces `{}` around `{$tweet->id}`

Comment: The form opening tags are also inside a `foreach` loop and `one` single closing tag is outside that loop.

Comment: well spotted @JoshBonnick - I'll include this in my answer

Comment: Hi, thank you fro your time but i changed the following things like you said and now instead i am getting this is my URL %7B"id":1,"user_id":1,"body":"a","created_at":"2020-10-20T09:58:58.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-10-20T09:58:58.000000Z"%7D

Comment: you sure you're doing a post method?

Comment: Route::post("/comments/{tweet}", "App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@store"); this is my route i have had to change it to account for the my laravel version which is laravel 8

Comment: For starters, you can change your route to this: 
Route::post("/comments/{tweet}", "CommentController@store");

Comment: Then change your `return redirect('/comments/{$tweet->id}');` in the controller to this:  `return redirect('/comments/$tweet->id');` You don't need the { } braces there

Comment: I am still getting the same string in my URL

Comment: can you do a print_r($tweet) inside your controller action, just to confirm it is the tweet you expect?

Comment: Also, your redirect is wrong, you're trying to go to the same route that you've posted to

Comment: I just did a print_r and it is still not the right tweet id and also the print_r does not work if i put action="/comments/{{$tweet}}"

Comment: You need to debug your code a little more and then perhaps edit/make a new question if you cannot solve it, this one is becoming too broad

Answer (score 0):

The `POST` method will not accept the ID from the action. You may use a hidden field for ID in the form.